# Unable to access localhost Jenkins from the another computer in the same network

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, localhost, port

Unable to access localhost Jenkins from another computer in the same network. These are the steps I did

1) I pinged the ip address of the computer from another computer and it is successful
2) I change the Jenkins URL in the config to - `http://[IP of the machine:8080]`
3) Turned off the firewall.

However I am not able to access this url from the same computer or another computer - `http://[IP of the machine:8080]`

Any time would be appreciated. Followed all the steps, not sure if i need to use a service like xamp or mamp

i also did ifconfig and this is what i got. My jenkins port is running on :8080 and i dont know what url to add to my jenkins so i can access it from other network within the same computer

Also what other steps i need to do, do i need to open the port from somwhere?

Answer (score 0):

For Instance, your IP of Jenkins master is  192.169.x.x.

Open the Port 8080 via firewall and then change the URL of jenkins from "Manage Jenkins >>Config Sys >> Jenkins Location>" to "http://192.169.x.x:8080"

Now you can access it from other machine on same network domain.Just have to hit the url http://192.169.x.x:8080

You can now create different users with different privileges for the same.

You can find it under Manage Jenkins >> Manage Users >> Create Users.

Comment: Hi, yes i saw this answer from another post but this did not work for me as i mentioned above

Comment: Can you give me access to hour vm i will fix it

Comment: it is not a VM it is a real machine

Comment: also what do you mean ip of the jenkins master, it is the IP of the wifi or mac right? which one should i add it to the jenkins config?

Comment: also, what do i type in the terminal to find the x.x ?

Comment: do ipconfig if its windows or ifconfig if linux . Look for ipv4 ip in that output that is  ip on which Jenkins is running.

Comment: i dont see anything called ipv4 only inet

Comment: Can you post screenshot of that output ?

Comment: i just added, please take a look

Comment: 10.23.25.1 try this. if its urgent can we discuss on call  to understand things ?

Comment: can we have a call ?